# Unable to integrated sass to ReactJS storybook

Tags: reactjs, plugins, sass, storybook

I tried out [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) for ReactJS. I followed this [blog](https://fathomtech.io/blog/create-a-react-component-library-using-create-react-app/) to create the same. Everthing is working as expected, I was able to publish the app to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

When I tried to add SASS support for my plugin, the app fails to run. CSS, and CSS modules are working fine.
I have gone through their [docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config).
I also tried out the suggestions reported in this [issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12464) in github.
I tried downgrading the packages (css-loader, sass-loader, style-loader, & scss) that I am using. None of these helped.

Node version: 16 (I also tried with 12)

This is my package,json

```
{
  "name": "plugin",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Starter template to get up and running quickly with React and Storybook",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "private": false,
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.41.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "compile": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/stories --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,stories.js,stories.jsx,__snapshots__",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.7",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/testing-react": "^0.0.17",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

I would very much appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance.
If some one could direct me to some sample code with proper SASS integration that would also be helpful

Comment: I don't recommend to follow any blog tutorials, the are usualny not up to date, use [official documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction). Also check [examples](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/next/examples) they are updated and tested with every new release.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? My error message is different but it's basically the same scenario (and I've followed the official documentation)

Comment: No, I wasn't able to fix it. I eventually moved to create react library

Answer (score 0):

As you might know Storybook is based on Webpack of the fourth versions.
This summer these loaders was updated and stop to support of the fourth version. List of the latest compatibles loaders and it versions for Webpack 4 below:

- [style-loader –  v2.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/releases)
- [css-loader – v5.2.7](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases)
- [sass-loader – v10.1.1](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases)

Just downgrade loaders to this versions and try again.

Also be sure that you configured webpack or installed [@storybook/preset-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/preset-scss) to ".storybook/main.js"

I hope that I helped you.

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried the package versions that you had suggested & added `preset-scss` into `main.js`, I am still not able to run it